# How to add multiple windows setup in one USB?

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I've been trying to create a 'multiboot' USB to install Windows 10 and 7 both from the same USB drive and I could not find any reliable solution yet, Is there a way to create such USB drive that can boot on older and newer systems alike?

What I have already tried:

**Ventoy** - Sometimes on older hardware, installation gets stuck with a black screen and a blinking cursor.

**Easy2boot** - Very slow and gets stuck on windows logo very often.

**Yumi** - Apparently isn't compatible with UEFI

**WinsetupfromUSB** - same as E2B, slow and gets stuck very often.

Comment: Why not just 2 USB sticks? Would seem far less effort-intensive. They're about $£€ 3 these days.

Comment: @Tetsujin Because It's not for my home use, the firm I work for provides PCs on rent, so I have to install windows in like 6-7 machines at the same time (+ 2 more persons doing the same thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished setting one up using AIO Boot from [aioboot.com](https://www.aioboot.com/)
It supports both Legacy and UEFI. They have loads of documentation and how to videos to get you through the setup.

I put Win 7, 8, 8.1, 10, Server 2008, 2012, 2019 Standard, Hiren, and Linux Mint all on the same drive. No more lugging and keeping track of a dozen USB drives! I've only tested Win 10, Mint, and Hiren so far, but have had no issues. I don't think 7 will work with UEFI, but it was so easy to add, I did anyway.

Answer (score 0):

WinSetupFrom USB and Easy2Boot are two popular solutions. Both seem to give **you** problems but not 1000s of other people. Maybe your USB flash drive is  faulty or is a fake? Easy2Boot has a QEMU_MENU_TEST.cmd file in the root which allows you to quickly test that the USB drive boots on an emulated virtual machine. If that works then the issue is with your BIOS settings - if QEMU gives the same issues, then you have a faulty USB drive.